# Group permission - Sharepoint Online Powershell

Tags: powershell, client-object-model, online

I would like to have a report of which sites a specific group or user has on all the SharePoint sites.

I have this group called `SPGroup` and I want to see on which sites this group has permissions on, including all subsites.

Can this be done by using Client context?

I can't find anything where it explains how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find WHERE this group has permissions at SITE COLLECTION level, but not WHAT permissions and NOT subsites, then use SharePoint Online Management Shell and:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site
```

e.g.

```
   $sites=(get-SPOSite).Url
  foreach($site in $sites){ foreach($user in (get-spouser -site $site)){ if($user.DisplayName -eq "SPGroup") {write-host $site}}}
```

Comment: I need to check permissions on the subsite level. Thanks anyway

Comment: If I find the time, I'll write CSOM for the subsites and change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This exists on the RoleAssignment.Groups property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.associatedgroups.aspx

```
# Note -- I have a function for creating the context.
$Ctx = Get-Context $Credentials $SubSiteURL
$Ctx.Load($Ctx.Web.RoleAssignments.Groups)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
ForEach($Group in $Ctx.Web.RoleAssignments.Groups)
{
    $Ctx.Load($Group)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Write-Output ("{0} -> {1} -> {2}" -f $Group.Id, $Group.Title, $Group.Description)
}
```

Output:

```
3 -> Excel Services Viewers -> Members of this group can view pages, list items, and documents.  If the document has a
 server rendering available, they can only view the document using the server rendering.
7 -> IT TEST AREA Members -> 
5 -> IT TEST AREA Owners -> 
6 -> IT TEST AREA Visitors -> 
21 -> SharingLinks....OrganizationEdit.... -> This group is for OrganizationEdit sharing links on item 'DocURL'
26 -> TESt Members -> Use this group to grant people contribute permissions to the SharePoint site: TESt
27 -> TESt Visitors -> Use this group to grant people read permissions to the SharePoint site: TESt
```

Just write something to iterate through all items under the root web, like this.

```
Function Get-SubSites($Credentials, $SiteURL)
{
    # Check if this is the parent web or not
    $Context = Get-Context $Credentials $SiteURL
    $Context.Load($Context.Web.Webs)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    # Collect whatever you want and append it to an array
    $Report += $Context.Web.Url
    ForEach($Web in $Context.Web.Webs)
    {
        Get-SubSites $Credentials $Web.Url
    }
    $Context.Dispose()
}
$Script:Report = @()
```